# node js 12.7 not supporting dynamic key in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I read that in ecma6 dynamic key object can be made so i have just upgraded node to 0.12.7 and i still get the error

```
    node /var/www/games/node_modules/app.js 
/var/www/games/node_modules/app.js:61
            obj = {[key]: 'ES6!'};

                   ^
```

My code

```
      var key = 'DYNAMIC_KEY';
        obj = {[key]: 'ES6!'};

console.log(obj);
```

node 0.12.7

```
    { http_parser: '2.3',
  node: '0.12.7',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '14',
  openssl: '1.0.1p' }
```

Comment: can you verify your node version ? `node -v` and npm version `npm -v`

Comment: Node 12.7 doesn't exist. Do you mean 0.12.7? That version has only limited support for ES6 features. The latest version has better support (still limited though). I suggest to read https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ to learn which features are available.

Comment: The latest version of Node is v5. And again, ES6 is not fully supported yet. Some features are and some are not.

Comment: RE : https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/

Comment: in official site theres only v4.2.2

Comment: Really? I see two big green buttons on https://nodejs.org/en/ . One says "v4.2.2 LTS", the other says "v5.1.0 Stable".

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ oh i was i had this saved on bookmarks dnt why they didnt update their download page fine

Comment: `/download` also has two buttons, but less obvious: `LTS` and `Stabel`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question about ES6 feature support in Node are not useful. Much more up to date information is available on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node 0.12.7 does *not* have computer object properties.  Node 4.x and 5.x do however.  You can check any features using this great compatibility checker:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Edit: What you're asking for is listed under "object literal extensions".

Comment: Direct link: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties

Comment: The current versions are 4.2.2 LTS and 5.1.0 Stable.  0.10 and 0.12 are older releases.  https://nodejs.org/en/download/